# Custom http header data retrieval through spring security for finding the role and user information

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, role-base-authorization

I have a requirement where I need to retrieve the ROLE info and user info in my Spring web application. The information will come through HTTP Header from another application and I need to parse that data and use in my application.

What I want is:

1. When someone navigate to my web application, the request header will have the ROLE and USER data, so how to retrieve those using Spring security.

   For example: There is an web app where user login and enter into the application and there inside one link will be present to my web app and once click they will navigate to my web app and I need to get those ROLS and USER info.
2. I want to store that data into some kind of Session so that I can carry out only those operations which are applicable to that particular user only.

Can you please tell me how I can implement that functionality? Thanks.

Comment: 1, write a filter that does that and creates an `Authentication` object, use the `AbstractPreAuthenticationFilter` as a base. 2. don't bother, spring security does that for you if you integrate properly using 1.

Comment: so, one doubt, when user clock on a link which will navigate to my web app, what filter and code i have put into? Can you please point at something specific. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: For example: A user logins to a system and click on a link "monitor" and it navigates to my monitor appliction where i need to access the ROLE and USER info, and URL will be like: http://localhost:8080/mywebapp

Comment: Well i'm not going to write your code for you, that is your job... I suggest a read of the [Spring Security guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/)... What you need to do is to ensure a properly filled authentication object, after that it is just a matter of correct security configuration.

Comment: okay thanks for the pointer.. so we can get the custom http header information through Spring right? by applying filter and authentication.

Comment: You have access to the `HttpServletRequest` so you can access anything you want...